# Semantics UI React - Dropdown Value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, semantic-ui-react

Good Afternoon,

I am trying to figure out how I can read the value of the selected item in the dropdown that I am building. The value from the dropdown will provide me the number of columns that I need to build a grid to be able to upload photos.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import HeaderBar from "./modules/header";
import "./BandsPageScreen.css";
// import Temp from "../../img/tempphoto.png";
// import Logo from "../../img/logo.png";
import {
  Dropdown,
  DropdownItem,
  DropdownMenu,
  Grid,
  GridColumn,
  Segment,
} from "semantic-ui-react";

const CustomizePhotoScreen = ({ history }) => {
  const [template, setTemplate] = useState("");

  const options = [
    { key: 1, text: "2 Portrait Photos", value: 1 },
    { key: 2, text: "5 Photos", value: 2 },
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log({ template });
  }, [template]);

  const GenerateDropDown = () => {
    return (
      <Dropdown
        placeholder="Select Template"
        selection
        options={options}
        value={template}
        onChange={(e) => setTemplate(e.target.value)}
      ></Dropdown>
    );
  };

  const GenerateGrid = () => {};
  return (
    <>
      <HeaderBar screen="photoinsert"></HeaderBar>
      <GenerateDropDown />
    </>
  );
};

export default CustomizePhotoScreen;
```

If I change the `onChange={(e) => console.log(e.target.value)}` the console says undefind. What do I need to do to receive the value in the options?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't using OnChange Correctly

```
import _ from "lodash";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import HeaderBar from "./modules/header";
import "./BandsPageScreen.css";
// import Temp from "../../img/tempphoto.png";
// import Logo from "../../img/logo.png";
import { Dropdown, Grid, GridColumn, Image } from "semantic-ui-react";

const CustomizePhotoScreen = ({ history }) => {
  const [template, setTemplate] = useState(0);

  const options = [
    { key: 1, text: "2 Portrait Photos", value: 2 },
    { key: 2, text: "5 Photos", value: 5 },
  ];

  useEffect(() => {}, [template]);

  const handleSelection = (event, data) => {
    setTemplate(data.value);
  };
  console.log({ template });

  const columns = _.times(5, (i) => (
    <Grid.Column key={i}>
      <Image src="https://react.semantic-ui.com/images/wireframe/image.png" />
    </Grid.Column>
  ));

  const GenerateDropDown = () => {
    return (
      <Dropdown
        placeholder="Select Template"
        selection
        options={options}
        value={template}
        onChange={handleSelection}
      ></Dropdown>
    );
  };

  const GenerateGrid = () => {
    console.log({ columns });
    return <Grid>{columns}</Grid>;
  };
  return (
    <>
      <HeaderBar screen="photoinsert"></HeaderBar>
      <GenerateDropDown />
      <GenerateGrid />
    </>
  );
};

export default CustomizePhotoScreen;
```